# Deprecated QuerydslJpaReposiotry does not work anymore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a custom repository that needs the functionality of Querydsl as well as `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Till now my custom repository was like

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {
// Overriden methods
}

public class CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepository<T, ID> {
// Overriden implementations of methods defined in the interface
}
```

The great thing about this was that my custom implementation was not very different from the default implementation provided by `QuerydslJpaRepository` and thus I would use the `super` class methods with some modifications in mine like

```
public class CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepository<T, ID> {
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Optional<T> findOne(@NonNull Predicate predicate) {
        return super.findOne(modifierMethod(predicate));
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public <U extends T> U save(@NonNull U entity) {
        return super.save(otherModifierMethod(entity, false));
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public <S extends T> S saveCustom(@NonNull S entity) {
        return super.save(otherModifierMethod(entity, false));
    }
}
```

Note that I also have a `saveCustom` defined by me in the custom interface and I am providing its implementation with the help of the parent class.

This worked great but after Spring Boot 2.1, `QuerydslJpaRepository` has been deprecated in favour of `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor`. Now this class does not provide implementations of `save` or `delete` and thus I cannot use the `SimpleJpaRepository` methods if my implementation class inherits from `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor`.

In short, I need to reimpelement query and save/delete methods in my custom repository along with some custom methods of mine and I don't want to implement them from scratch. The current deprecation means my implementation can extend either from `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` which provides implementation of query methods only or from `SimpleJpaRepository` which means I lose the functionality of querydsl in my implementation.

**What I've done till now**

To work around this I have created 2 repositories

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomPagingSortingRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
// Only overrides save and delete type of methods and includes my customSave method

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomQuerydslRepository<T, ID> extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T> {
// Overrides all methods of the superclass and includes any custom methods of mine
}
```

and I have implemented them separately like

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class CustomPagingSortingRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomPagingSortingRepository<T, ID> {
// Implements all the methods of the interface using the parent class methods
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public class CustomQuerydslRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T> implements CustomQuerydslRepository<T, ID> {
// Implements all the methods of the interface using the parent class methods
}
```

and I inherit these 2 interfaces into my custom interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomPagingSortingQuerydslRepository<T, ID> extends CustomPagingSortingRepository<T,ID>,CustomQuerydslRepository<T, ID>  {
}
```

I thought this would work but this throws a type error which on close inspection I found to be because Spring is trying to create an implementation of `customSave` by itself and since it doesn't understand what this method has to do, it throws an error.

I am really in a fix now since the deprecated way was extremely clean and I don't want to implement half a dozen Beans for this to work.

**P.S.**
I have been thinking using Composition instead of Inheritance to get a handle to `SimpleJpaRepository` and `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` and use the methods in them that way but I have a feeling this is going to be against injection and a bad practice.